# Adding space after datagridview column is appending txt to txt file

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview that points to sql server to grab data, and when making a change to the grid and clicking "Update", it will send the update as needed to SQL server and also write a txt file to a location which shows all the columns that have been updated (like a log file). When I have it send to the log file, I'm trying to have the date and time stamped into the log file for each line.

For example here is my code that I am using and how it shows its work when done.

```
dg.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableWithAutoHeaderText;
dg.SelectAll();
Clipboard.SetDataObject(dg.GetClipboardContent());
File.AppendAllText(updatep.Replace(" ", string.Empty), Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text) + DateTime.Now + Environment.NewLine);
```

The Log file shows data like so:

```
DataColumn1(tab)datacolumn2(tab)datacolumn3dateandtime
```

I can re iterate if need be. I need it to show:

```
DataColumn1(tab)datacolumn2(tab)datacolumn3(tab/space)dateandtime
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just needed to add the tab/space in your string concatentation like so:

```
Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text) + "\t" + DateTime.Now + Environment.NewLine
```

Comment: well I just reverted my data back to it's original set and this is exactly what I needed.
Ever had a V8 moment? I just did

Comment: Yup, sometimes it just takes a fresh pair of eyes and suddenly a problem is solved. Done it to myself many times.